# Flutter Divider color is not expected when thickness is low

Tags: flutter, colors, divider

code:

```
    Divider(
      color: Color(0xffd2d2d2),
      thickness: 0.5,
      indent: indent,
      endIndent: endIndent,
    );
```

thickness: 10

[image: thickness10]

RGB(210,210,210) 0xffd2d2d2 which is expected

thickness: 0.5

[image: thickness0.5]

RGB(235,235,235)

how can i maintain the expected color when Divider thickness is 0.5

Answer (score 1):

**I think getting thicker doesn't mean getting more transparency**, if it's so.

Make your custom divider:

```
Container(width: double.infinity, height: 0.5 , color: Color(0xffd2d2d2),),
```

but the results looks similar:

[image]

code: [here](https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zz7206ds0730?lazy=false&split=50&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart)

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is not the Flutter's problem, i got same result when i use SwiftUI, the only way to solve this problem is find a darker color